# Boost.asio client/server TIME_WAIT why?

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I am trying to run some functional testing into some API.

My API has a client and a server side.
The client side just connects and sets a flag. The server just accepts connections.

This is a test case I have:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(client_can_connect_to_server) {
        boost::asio::io_service serverService;
        std::thread serverLoop([&serverService] { serverService.run(); }); 

        boost::asio::io_service clientService; 
        std::thread clientLoop([&clientService] { clientService.run(); }); 

        //    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms); Maybe wait for server loop to start...?


        auto connectionSuccess = connectTo("127.0.0.1", "54321", kAuthData, ioService); 

        BOOST_REQUIRE(blockForDurationOrWhile
                      (timeout,
                       [&] { return connectionSuccess.wait_for(0s) != std::future_status::ready; }) == ExitStatus::ConditionSatisfied);

        serverService.stop();
        clientLoop.join();
        serverService.join();    
    }
```

I am having trouble with 2 things here:

1. The connection is timed out more than half of the time, but sometimes works.
2. When finishing the program through the sucessful path to the end of the test, it seems that netstat shows some kind of socket leaks with the state `TIME_WAIT`. I am closing and shutting down sockets. I just cannot figure out what is wrong. This is shown for around 30-45 seconds after the app exits:

   tcp        0      0 ip6-localhost:52256     ip6-localhost:54321     TIME_WAIT
   tcp        0      0 ip6-localhost:54321     ip6-localhost:52256     TIME_WAIT

Code for client and server code is below:

```
std::future<bool> connectTo(std::string const & host,
                            std::string const & port,
                            std::string const & authData,
                            boost::asio::io_service & s,
                            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::duration timeout = kCortexTryConnectTimeout) {
    using namespace boost::asio;
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

    std::promise<bool> p;
    auto res = p.get_future();
    spawn
        (s,
         [&s, host, port, p = std::move(p)](yield_context yield) mutable {
            tcp::socket socket(s);
            BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(&socket) {
                std::cout << "Closing client socket\n";
                if (socket.is_open()) {
                    boost::system::error_code ec{};
                    socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
                    socket.close();
                    std::cout << "Client socket closed\n";
                }
            } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END

            std::cout << "Client trying to connect\n";
            tcp::resolver resolver(s);
            boost::system::error_code ec{boost::asio::error::operation_aborted};
            boost::asio::async_connect(socket, resolver.resolve({host, port}), yield[ec]);
            std::cout << "Client Connected\n";
            if (!ec) p.set_value(true);
            else p.set_value(false);
        });
    return res;
}
```

The server handles connections:

```
class ConnectionsAcceptorTask {
public:
    //Session handling for Cortex. Will move out of here
    class Session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Session> {
    public:
        explicit Session(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket) : _socket(std::move(socket)) {}
        void start() {}

        ~Session() {
            if (_socket.is_open()) {
                boost::system::error_code ec{};
                _socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
                _socket.close();
            }
        }
    private:
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
    };

    ConnectionsAcceptorTask(unsigned int port,
                            io_service & s)
        : _port(port),
          _ioService(&s)
    {}

    void operator()() {
        namespace ba = boost::asio;
        using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
        ba::spawn
            (*_ioService,
             [s = _ioService, port = this->_port](ba::yield_context yield) {

                tcp::acceptor acceptor
                    (*s,
                     tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
                acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::reuse_address(true));

                BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(&acceptor) {
                    std::cout << "Closing acceptor\n";
                    if (acceptor.is_open()) {
                        acceptor.close();
                        std::cout << "Acceptor closed\n";
                    }
                } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END

                for (;;) {
                    boost::system::error_code ec{};
                    tcp::socket socket(*s);
                    acceptor.async_accept(socket, yield[ec]); 

                    if (!ec) std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(socket))->start();
                }
            });
    }
private:
    unsigned int _port = 0;
    boost::asio::io_service * _ioService;
};
```

Comment: why the negative votes?

Comment: I see that when I do a synchronous ConnectTo it works. When I do an async connect to it does not work at all. But I am using two different io_service loops in different threads. Though, I am inside the same process, could that be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TIME_WAIT state is not a socket leak. It is a normal part of TCP connection tear-down, specified in RFC 793.

Comment: This means that, after the program is closed and cleaned up, I should still see that in netstat as part of normal behaviour?

Comment: what about hanging behavior? Why does that happen?

Comment: @GermánDiago: Yes, see for example here: http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html

Comment: If you have a problem that you can't restart the server due to it you might want to use `SO_REUSEADDR` for the server socket.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. It expires after two minutes.